# The inversion formula for the square root of a positive function

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose that $\hat{f}$, the  Fourier transform of $f$, is a positive function in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. Does there exists any function $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $|\hat{g}|^2=\hat{f}$?

Comment: so $f$ is the convolution of $g$ with itself; for example, if $f$ is a gaussian then $g$ is a gaussian with half the variance.

Comment: In other words  if $\hat{f}\geq0$, we are looking for the solution of the equation $f=g*g^* $ where $g^*(t)=\overline{g(-t)}$.  Hold in general?!

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581143/square-root-in-banach-algebra